# Grunticon: how to keep colors directives in file names when using svgmin

Tags: javascript, css, svg, colors, gruntjs

I usually use [Grunticon](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon) and I want to add aan [svgmin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-svgmin) task. I generally want to color my icons, but not all of all the possible colors. Maybe I want one icon red, another green ok?

In grunticon you pass the colors to be used while generating the optimized files with the filename, like 'myimage.colors-color1-color2.svg'.

The problem here is that svgmin treats the color portion like part of the extension, so when it generates the files, it swaps that portion with simply '.svg'.

My current configuration:

```
svgmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true, 
      cwd: 'src',
      src: ['*.svg'],
      dest: 'min',
      ext: '.svg'
    }]
  }
}
```

So myfile.colors-green.svg will be become myfile.svg, thus not retaining colors.

I could do this:

```
svgmin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true, 
      cwd: 'src',
      src: ['*.svg'],
      dest: 'min',
      ext: '[EVERY-POSSIBLE-COLORS.svg]'
    }]
  }
}
```

But it's not a real solution for me, since when using 4-5 colors per icon I would end up with a huge icons.data.svg.css.

I would simply like svgmin to retain the original color portion of the file. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone wants me to better explain, maybe.. I'm answering to my own question, so, this IS the right answer. And the answer is exactly this:

"skip the ext option"

Skip (do-not-use) the ext option you can see above and colors directives will be retained.